# Enhancing zoom performance

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I'm working on a C#/XAML WinRT application.  I have a canvas with many Path children.  I am using a GestureRecognizer and RenderTransform at the root level to support infinite panning and zooming around the canvas.  Translate transforms perform great, but I notice rendering lag when zooming.  I've tried using a BitmapCache on the canvas while zooming which visually makes it look like the children paths aren't redrawn during the zoom operating, but performance doesn't improve.

If I use a ScrollViewer around my canvas instead of custom zooming, performance is great and it looks a lot like my BitmapCache (child paths aren't cleaned up until zoom operating is done), but there are other aspects of the ScrollViewer I don't want.  Any suggestions on how to get custom RenderTransform to perform as well as ScrollViewer when scaling/zooming a canvas with a lot of child Paths?

Comment: Hi! If you found solution - provide it please.